# How to use the which() function with a pipe %>%

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

```
test <- c(1,2,0,5,0)

which(test == 0)

test %>% which(.==0)
test %>% which(,==0)
test %>% which( ==0)
```

I am trying to figure out how to pipe a vector into the which() function. Using which(test == 0) gives me the desired result but using a pipe on the last three lines all give me errors. How can I get the same result as which(test == 0) but using a pipe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use {...} to prevent dot from being inserted into `which` .  Without the brace brackets it would have inserted dot as a first argument as in `which(., . == 0)` .

```
library(dplyr)

test %>% { which(. == 0) }
## [1] 3 5
```

With magrittr we can use `equals`

```
library(magrittr)

test %>% equals(0) %>% which
## [1] 3 5
```

To use |> create a list containing `test` where the component name is dot.

```
test |>
  list(. = _) |>
  with(which(. == 0))
## [1] 3 5
```

Comment: or `test |> {  \(.) which(. == 0) }()`

Comment: That works but I was trying to avoid that given the questionable readability.

Answer (score 4):

You have 2 functions, `which` and `==`. But binary operator functions like `+`, `*` and `==` don't make much sense to pipe into.

```
> (test == 0) |> which()
[1] 3 5
> (test == 0) %>% which()
[1] 3 5
```

You can write `test == 0` using normal function notation instead of the infix notation for binary operators, `"=="(test, 0)`, and with that syntax you could pipe it all, but it kills the readability for me:

```
test %>% `==`(0) %>% which()
[1] 3 5
```

Comment: Or you could do `test %>% \`==\`(0) %>% which()`

Comment: Thank you, this definitely works. Does anyone know why test cant be piped into which(. ==0)? My understanding was that pipe simply passes into the first argument of the next function. So I dont get why test %>% which(.==0) doesn't work the same as which(test==0)

Comment: Your argument to `which` is not `test`, your argument to `which` is `test == 0`. This is why `(test == 0) |> which()` works, `test == 0` is the argument to `which`. You can't pipe into just a part of an argument.

Comment: If you wanted to add `x` and `y` together and take the square root, you could do `(x + y) %>% sqrt()` or `x %>% "+"(y) %>% sqrt()`, but not `x %>% sqrt( + y)` or `x %>% sqrt(. + y)`.

Comment: This explanation/example makes perfect sense, thanks!